# Big-O analysis of permutation algorithm

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, big-o

```
result = False
def permute(a,l,r,b):
    global result
    if l==r:
        if a==b:
            result = True
    else:
        for i in range(l, r+1):
            a[l], a[i] = a[i], a[l]
            permute(a, l+1, r, b)
            a[l], a[i] = a[i], a[l]

string1 = list("abc")
string2 = list("ggg")
permute(string1, 0, len(string1)-1, string2)
```

So basically I think that finding each permutation takes n^2 steps (times some constant) and to find all permutations should take n! steps. So does this make it O(n^2 * n!) ? and if so does the n! take over, making it just O(n!)?

Thanks

edit: this algorithm might seem weird for just finding permutations, and that is because i'm also using it to test for anagrams between the two strings. I just haven't renamed the method yet sorry

Comment: @Primusa I got you, thanks. +1 for your answer. Let's clean up comments here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finding each permutation doesn't take `O(N^2)`. Creating each permutation happens in `O(1)` time. While it is tempting to say that this `O(N)` because you assign a new element to each index `N` times per permutation, each permutation shares assignments with other permutations.

When we do:

```
a[l], a[i] = a[i], a[l]
permute(a, l+1, r, b)
```

All subsequent recursive calls of `permute` down the line have this assignment already in place.

In reality, assignments only happen each time `permute` is called, which is [image] times. We can then determine the time complexity to build each permutation using some limit calculus. We take the number of assignments over the total number of permutations as N approaches infinity.

We have:

[image]

Expanding the sigma:

[image]

The limit of the sum is the sum of the limits:

[image]

At this point we evaluate our limits and all of the terms except the first collapse to zero. Since our result is a constant, we get that our complexity per permutation is `O(1)`.

[image]

However, we're forgetting about this part:

```
if l==r:
    if a==b:
        result = True
```

The comparison of `a == b` (between two lists) occurs in `O(N)`. Building each permutation takes `O(1)`, but our comparison at the end, which occurs for each permutation, actually takes `O(N)`. This gives us a time complexity of `O(N)` per permutation.

This gives you `N!` permutations times `O(N)` for each permutation giving you a total time complexity of `O(N!) * O(N)` = `O(N * N!)`.

Your final time complexity doesn't reduce to `O(N!)`, since `O(N * N!)` is still an order of magnitude greater than `O(N!)`, and only constant terms get dropped (same reason why `O(NlogN) != O(N)`).